# PYTHON: how can I add a linear regression to this bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

how can I add a linar regression to this bokeh?, I have trouble with this, and dont know  how to add to the figure the lr (don't know how to add to the curdoc expression). I've seen other posts, but havent found the way to add it to the bokeh. Please, help me with this showing how to add that line to the figure.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df

df = df.copy()

SIZES = list(range(6, 22, 3))
COLORS = Spectral5
N_SIZES = len(SIZES)
N_COLORS = len(COLORS)

# data cleanup
df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
df.yr = df.yr.astype(str)
del df['name']

columns = sorted(df.columns)
discrete = [x for x in columns if df[x].dtype == object]
continuous = [x for x in columns if x not in discrete]

def create_figure():
    xs = df[x.value].values
    ys = df[y.value].values
    x_title = x.value.title()
    y_title = y.value.title()

    kw = dict()
    if x.value in discrete:
        kw['x_range'] = sorted(set(xs))
    if y.value in discrete:
        kw['y_range'] = sorted(set(ys))
    kw['title'] = "%s vs %s" % (x_title, y_title)

    p = figure(height=600, width=800, tools='pan,box_zoom,hover,reset', **kw)
    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_title
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_title

    if x.value in discrete:
        p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pd.np.pi / 4

    sz = 9
    if size.value != 'None':
        if len(set(df[size.value])) > N_SIZES:
            groups = pd.qcut(df[size.value].values, N_SIZES, duplicates='drop')
        else:
            groups = pd.Categorical(df[size.value])
        sz = [SIZES[xx] for xx in groups.codes]

    c = "#31AADE"
    if color.value != 'None':
        if len(set(df[color.value])) > N_COLORS:
            groups = pd.qcut(df[color.value].values, N_COLORS, duplicates='drop')
        else:
            groups = pd.Categorical(df[color.value])
        c = [COLORS[xx] for xx in groups.codes]

    p.circle(x=xs, y=ys, color=c, size=sz, line_color="white", alpha=0.6, hover_color='white', hover_alpha=0.5)

    return p


def update(attr, old, new):
    layout.children[1] = create_figure()


x = Select(title='X-Axis', value='mpg', options=columns)
x.on_change('value', update)

y = Select(title='Y-Axis', value='hp', options=columns)
y.on_change('value', update)

size = Select(title='Size', value='None', options=['None'] + continuous)
size.on_change('value', update)

color = Select(title='Color', value='None', options=['None'] + continuous)
color.on_change('value', update)

controls = column(x, y, color, size, width=200)
layout = row(controls, create_figure())

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Crossfilter"
```

Comment: you mean to say LR line to bokeh right?

Comment: yes ... but have problems adding it to the figure

Comment: wait lemme try to explain in my style, please give me a moment.